# Help with set theory proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is a problem from Munkres Topology 2nd Edition. The question is,

"Here is a "proof" that every relation $C$ that is both symmetric and transitive is also reflexive: "Since $C$ is symmetric, $aCb$ implies $bCa.$ Since $C$ is transitive, $aCb$ and $bCa$ together imply $aCa$, as desired." Find the flaw in this argument. "

Here is my proof. My proff says that my proof is in correct, but I can't seem to find the error.

The reflexive property is not dependent upon transitivity or symmetry; it is a unique property. Claiming that transitivity implies the relation is reflexive is the flaw of the "proof." Consider the relation $\sim$ on a subset $C$ of the Cartesian product $AxA.$ Let $C={a,b,c}$ and $$D={(a,b),(b,a),(a,c),(b,c),(c,a),(c,b)}.$$ Clearly, $\forall a,b,c\in C$,$x\sim y$ implies $y\sim x$. Also,  $\forall a,b,c\in C, x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$ implies $x\sim z,$ but $a\not\sim a$ since $(a,a)\not\in D$, which shows the relation is not reflexive.  Therefore, a transitive, symmetric relation is not reflexive in general.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Your "counterexample" is not transitive. If **there exists** an $x$ such that $aCx$ (or $xCa$), then the proof does show that $aCa$. If poor $a$ is unrelated to anybody, the proof does not go through.

Comment: So I need to "throw out" either $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$?

Comment: The flaw in the proof is precisely that you are not guaranteed that there exists a $b$ such that $aCb$ for each $a$.

Comment: The triviallest counterexample has nobody related to anybody, the empty relation. For something slightly less trivial, have $a,b,c$ and relation $bCb$, $bCc$, $cCb$, $cCc$. Note I did not mention $a$.  For a bigger example, let our set be $\pi$ plus the integers, and let $C$ be any equivalence relation on the integers. Then on the set $\{\pi\}$ union the integers, we have a transitive symmetric relation, but it is not reflexive, since $\pi$ is not related to itself, or anybody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation you defined isn't transitive: $a\sim b$ and $b\sim a$, so if this relation were transitive then we would have $a\sim a$. As you point out, $a\not\sim a$, hence $D$ is not transitive.

Comment: But if that were the case, then wouldn't $(a,a)\in D$ therefore showing that it is also reflexive? Also, the definition for transitivity in my book defines transitivity as: if $xCy$ and $yCz \rightarrow xCz$.

Comment: Yes: this is why $D$ is not transitive. $D$ is transitive if and only if, whenever $(x,y)\in D$ and $(y,z)\in D$, we have $(x,z)\in D$. But taking $x=z=a$ and $y=b$, we have $(a,b)\in D$ and $(b,a)\in D$ and $(a,a)\not\in D$, so $D$ is not transitive.

To come up with a counterexample to the claim, you would need to exhibit a relation which *is* transitive and symmetric (see André Nicolas's comment for some such counterexamples).

Comment: Ah okay, I guess my comment above wasn't "clicking" for me. Thanks a lot for the quick responses!